# An extra step to avoid losing user data even if user session is Hijacked

Tags: php, session, security, local-storage

I was thinking about an extra security measure for protecting my web site user data, even if his session is hijacked. please give me pointers, also it might be helpful to others who is thinking about extra security.

my plan is to use an extra key like session id in local storage of the browser, there can be an argument here that, it might not work for some browsers, but anyway my application is using web socket, so i can assume they have local storage too.

So.. when user logs in i will assign a key to be stored in Local storage, and after that for any secure data to be requested from server through a POST or AJAX  should include this key as part of the request, and this verification of the key is on top of session id verification.

What you guys think, will this provide me a bit more security against session hijacking(may be not 100 %  but still, it might make the hackers life difficult).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most cases do not have to be so serious, but if deemed necessary:

http://php.net/manual/en/session.security.php

This is very usefull too:

http://wblinks.com/notes/secure-session-management-tips

Answer (score 0):

so you want to avoid data losing for miscellaneous  users...you dont need to care about loosing data when session hijacked since user who do this will definitely miscellaneous user ..and a regular user wont do this